I need a mathematically written well financial mathematics book.
I am a senior year mathematics student with not perfectly good but a good background in statistics and probability and beginner-level knowledge of finance and financial mathematics. This year, I am doing my senior project about option pricing models (Black Scholes, Heston, SABR). However, when I write my project report, I sometimes struggle to explain things in a mathematical way since most of the resources I am reading are not written too mathematically. That's why, to look as a reference, I am looking for a book that explains things mathematically about financial mathematics, especially option pricing models. Could you help me please to find this kind of book?

Perhaps Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance, the first volume focusses on the binomial asset pricing model and the second one on continuous time models.
